# set variable to another variable by id

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am working with Google Maps and I am trying to create a sidebar that enables different KML overlays.  I have put the KML layers into variables with the same as the ID tag of the button to press to activate them, in hopes to call that ID as the variable, which can then be used in the setMap function.
Not sure if this is actually possible

In this script here I am trying to make it so you press element with ID tag 'kml1', set testvar='kml1', and then be able to put testvar.setMap(the_Map) in place of kml1.setMap(the_Map), as testvar==kml1

jQuery

```
kml1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.domain.com/map_overlay1.txt", {
            preserveViewport: true,
        });
        kml2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.odomain.com/map_overlay2.txt", {
            preserveViewport: true,
        });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.kml_item').toggle(
                function() {
                    for (i=0; i<50; i++) {
                        testvar = this.id
                        if (testvar == 'kml' + i) {
                            testvar.setMap(the_Map);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                },
                function() {
                    for (i=0; i<50; i++) {
                        testvar = this.id
                        if (testvar == 'kml' + i) {
                            testvar.setMap(null);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            );
    })
```

associated HTML

```
<div id="kml1" class="kml_item">KML 1</div>
            <div id="kml2" class="kml_item">KML 2</div>
```

Comment: Careful with `i` it's leaking to the global scope in both loops. Can cause confusion and trouble. Don't forget to use `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's really kosher to answer your own question on this site, but I figured out another method, although I do believe my initial problem of using an ID tag as a variable is unsolvable the way I was approaching it. Instead of each KML layer in a separate variable, I put them together in an array.  Giving the clickable divs a number for a title tag allows the function to then count up until the array item matches the title number for the div and places that item from the array onto the map.

KML array

```
kml_arr = [
            new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.domain.com/map_overlay1.txt", {
            preserveViewport: true,
        }),
            new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.domain.com/map_overlay2.txt", {
            preserveViewport: true,
        })
        ]
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.kml_item').toggle(
                function() {
                    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}, 200);
                    for (i=0; i<50; i++) {
                        if (i == this.title) {
                            kml_arr[i].setMap(the_Map);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#d0d0d0'}, 200);
                    for (i=0; i<50; i++) {
                        if (i == this.title) {
                            kml_arr[i].setMap(null);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
    })
```

associated HTML

```
                <div title="0" id="kml1" class="kml_item">KML 1</div>
            <div title="1" id="kml2" class="kml_item">KML 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try a `.click()` function

```
   $('#kml1').click(function(){
      new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.domain.com/map_overlay1.txt", {
            preserveViewport: true,
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get what you're after with a few tweaks.

```
// These kml objects will be attached to the global window object at
// window.kml1
// or
// window['kml1']
var kml1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.domain.com/map_overlay1.txt", {
        preserveViewport: true,
    });
var kml2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.odomain.com/map_overlay2.txt", {
        preserveViewport: true,
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.kml_item').click(function() {
        // Access the various kml objects and set the_Map
        var kml = window[this.id]
        if(kml.getMap()) {
            kml.setMap(null);
        }
        else {
            kml.setMap(the_Map);
        }
    });
});
```